# Can Sass leave a literal $ in a selector after compiling?

Tags: sass, velocity

In short, I'd like to process a file through Sass, but then through Velocity later.

I need Sass spit out something like the following after compilation:

```
.btn-$right {
  a: b;
}
```

However, the most logical attempt I made results in a compilation error:

```
.btn-#{"$start"} {
  font-size: 12px
}
```

The error:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after ".btn-": expected selector, was "$start"
    on line 1 of style.scss
```

Comment: `.btn-$right` isn't legal in CSS. See [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

Comment: After Sass process my file, velocity will process it as well, and it will turn .btn-$right into either .bnt-right or .btn-left depending on the value of the $right variable, as assigned in a velocity macro call.

Comment: The SASS compiler will not allow you to output invalid CSS, aside from [a few exceptions](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/stable/test/sass/engine_test.rb#L863-L883).